Nginx - Wordpress redirect
I have one problem about the redirecting I want to make redirect to example.com/product-bag.html to example.com/product-bag
I want to redirect but not affect the website's keywords in Google.
What I Try
when I add the code below:
rewrite ^/ \.html$ https://example.com permanent;
When restarting Nginx, I get an error saying I can't save the file
I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do or not. Thank you!

Could you please try to use the given code in your nginx configuration. It should works for you.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    # Redirect from .html to desired URL.
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1 permanent;
}

